# How to convert telegram voice message to text by using Whisper

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, whisper

I'm trying to make a telegram bot that can convert telegram voice messages to text but in Internet I could't find anything useful, I also asked this question to ChatGPT but I could't get the result. So I decided to asked you about the solution to this problem maybe somebody have the solution or got the same problem. Sorry for my English I'm studing it.

```
import telebot
import openai
import whisper
import numpy as np

bot = telebot.TeleBot('#')
openai.api_key = '#'


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_start_help(message):
    user_first_name = str(message.chat.first_name)
    bot.reply_to(message,
                 f"Привет, {user_first_name}! Добро пожаловать в мир PyProject-Assistant, "
                 f"просто задай вопрос и я найду на него ответ\nProject was made by #")


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    print(message)
    completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model='#',
        messages=[
            {'role': 'user', 'content': message.text.capitalize()}
        ]
    )
    to_say = completion["choices"][0]["message"]["content"]

    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, to_say)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['voice'])
def voice_processing(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Пока что я не умею обрабатывать voice messages, но вскоре научусь')
    file_info = bot.get_file(message.voice.file_id)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
    aud_array = np.frombuffer(downloaded_file, np.int8).flatten().astype(np.float32) / 32768.0
    speech_model = whisper.load_model('small')
    result = speech_model.transcribe(aud_array)
    print(result['text'])


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```